# strptime() argument 1 must be string, not None

Tags: python, datetime, flask, strptime

I'm trying to develop some unit tests to my Flask application and I'm struggling with this one.

I want to test my **create_politician** function/view and it requires two dates (start and end date) and I can't figure out how to pass it or what is the format the **create politician Form** is taking the arguments.

**My unit test:**

```
class TestPolitician(BaseTestCase):

    #ensures a logged user can create a politician

    def test_create_politician(self):
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("21/11/06", "%d/%m/%y")
        with self.client:
            self.client.post('/login', data=dict(
                email = 'adm@min.com', password='admin'
            ), follow_redirects=True)

            response = self.client.post(
                '/create_politician',
                data=dict(publicName='Antonio Costa',
                          completeName='Antonio Cenas Costa',
                          startDate="21/11/06", endDate="21/11/06"),
                follow_redirects=True)

            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertIn(b'New entry was successfully posted. Thanks.', response.data)
```

**My Form**

```
class PoliticForm(FlaskForm):
  publicName = StringField('Public Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician public name.")])
  completeName = StringField('Complete Name', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter politician complete name.")])
  startDate = DateField('Start Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=[DataRequired("Please enter the politician start Date.")])
  endDate = DateField('End Date', format='%m-%d-%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
  submit = SubmitField('Add Politician', validators=(validators.Optional(),))
```

and my **create_politician view**

```
@politicians_blueprint.route("/create_politician", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def create_politician():
  form = PoliticForm()

  if request.method == "POST":
    stDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print stDate
    endDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('date2'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    flash(form.validate())
    newpolitician = Politic(form.publicName.data, form.completeName.data, stDate,endDate)
    db.session.add(newpolitician)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted. Thanks.')
    return redirect(url_for('home.home'))

  elif request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("createPolitician.html", form=form)
```

**create_politician.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <main class="hero-section">
    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <div class="container">
      <h4>Add Entry</h4>
      <form method="POST" action="/create_politician">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.publicName.label }}
          {{ form.publicName }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.completeName.label }}
          {{ form.completeName }}
        </div>

       <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date">
       Date
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text"/>
     </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="date2">
       Date2
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
       <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa ">
        </i>
       </div>
       <input class="form-control" id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text"/>
      </div>
     </div>

        {{ form.submit(class="btn-primary") }}

      </form>
      </div>


    </div>
  </main>
{% endblock %}
```

What is the format of the string that **strptime** is expecting?

Comment: Assuming the title of this question is the error message, than I'd say that in first place it needs to be a string, not a NoneType -- that seems kind of obvious from the text. I don't know Flask, but my guess is that `request.form.get` returns `None` when it fails, and you check for that. | Looking at the [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), we see that "Return the default value if the requested data doesn’t exist." and that `None` is the default default value.

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you are referring to the date fields as "date" and "date2"

```
 request.form.get('date')
 request.form.get('date2')
```

In your form and test code, they are defined as "startDate" and "endDate", so you should update the view code to use those names.

```
stDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('startDate'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
endDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('endDate'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: I don't think so, because on my **create_politician.html** I create two data input fields with (date and date2) for startDate and endDate. Post updated.